# How can i link one AlertDialog to two actions?

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

Let's say i have a button which inserts a number to the front of a linked list and a button that inserts a number to the end of the linked list. I have this [AlertDaialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ianIF.jpg) and I'm trying to use it with both buttons. How can i differentiate the buttons from one another so that when i press "OK" on the dialog, the onClick method know where to insert the number(front or end).
I've tried somthing like this but it doesn't work, only the default case gets activated.

```
ok.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String input = inputText.getText().toString().trim();
            int numberInput = Integer.parseInt(input);

            switch (v.getId()){
                case R.id.btn_front: //insert to the beginning
                    break;
                case R.id.btn_end: //insert to the end
                    break;
                default: Log.e("DIALOG_ERROR", "Error!");
            }


        }
    });
```

Comment: Why not just have 2 onClickListeners?  I'm not sure you're saving anything here by reusing one AlertDialog

Comment: @Scott is it good practice, though? Sorry for stupid questions, i just started learning android.

Comment: I think it's good practice to prioritize simpler workflows over reducing the # of lines in code.  If you have a common AlertDialog setup you want to reuse, create a class with the details but add the listener as a parameter.  That would achieve both goals.

Comment: @Scott Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Use a class that extend dialog like:
DialogClass obj=new DialogClass(context,true);
obj.show();
class will be:
public DialogClass(final Context context,Boolean isAddToFront) {
    super(context);
    setContentView(R.layout.dialog_layout);
    setTitle(Title);
TextView Ok = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ok);
Ok.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
             if(isAddToFront){
           /// Add to front
        }else{///add to back}
    });
```

}